# Azure Active Directory retrieving same credentials for all users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure Active Directory (AAD) to authenticate users logging in to my ASP.Net MVC website. In the home page, I should show the current logged in user information but it always shows my information not the logged in user. I have static class called Common.cs and it has FirstName, LastName, and Name as static strings.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
static Common()
    {
        ClaimsIdentity myPrincipal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        Authinticated = myPrincipal.IsAuthenticated;
        Name = myPrincipal.Name.ToString();
        var myPrincipalType = myPrincipal.GetType();
        if (myPrincipalType == typeof(ClaimsIdentity))
        {
            FirstName = myPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value != null? myPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value : "Test" ;
            LastName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;
            Role = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value;
            Name = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
        }
    }
```

In the View.cshtmlfile I have this code

```
<div>
@{
    var FirstName = MyWebsite.Models.Common.FirstName;
    var LastName = MyWebsite.Models.Common.LastName;
    var Name = MyWebsite.Models.Common.Name;
}
<p>FirstName = @FirstName</p>
<p>LastName = @LastName</p>
<p>Name = @Name</p>
</div>
```

Not sure what I'm missing and why it's caching my information in the website.

Answer (score 0):

**All you need to do is access `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` directly from your controller or your .cshtml file.**

It's not clear why you are using statics. If you have another undisclosed requirement, please include that in the question. Generally speaking, **statics shouldn't be used AT ALL to handle user information, this is a HUGE security risk** as statics are shared across user sessions and can introduce all sorts of risky race conditions. Also, statics work at a machine level, so if you ever scale out your web servers, whatever you're sharing in a static will not be share across the different servers.

In general, you should use sessions, cookies or external storage. The approach I suggested uses out-of-the-box mechanisms in ASP.Net that do the right thing.